# How to turn on/off the checkbox in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm such a fool.
I'd like to change the design of the check box with React.
The new design is `Checkbox.js`.I designed it in js.
I want to turn this on/off, but it never works.
I want to use clip-path, but when I use it, the checkbox doesn't work at all.
I really want to know the answer. Because of this, I spent 8 hours.
Please teach me the way. Please.

```
ListPage.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Checkbox from '../Checkbox/Checkbox';
import { MdKeyboardArrowDown } from 'react-icons/md';

function KeywordButton() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const changeOption = e => {
    setIsChecked(e.target.isChecked);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <CheckBoxWrap>
          <WrapBox>
            <BoxAndTextWrap>
              <CheckboxShell>
                <Checkbox onChange={changeOption} isChecked={isChecked} />
              </CheckboxShell>
              <TextBoxWrap> exercise </TextBoxWrap>
            </BoxAndTextWrap>
          </WrapBox>
        </CheckBoxWrap>
      </LeftModalWrap>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

```
Checkbox.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

function Checkbox({ isChecked, ...props }) {
  return (
    <LabelLabal>
      <A>
        <B type="checkbox" isChecked={isChecked} {...props} />
        <C>
          <D>
            <Icon viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12" />
            </Icon>
          </D>
        </C>
      </A>
    </LabelLabal>
  );
}

const LabelLabal = styled.label`
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const Icon = styled.svg`
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  stroke-width: 4;
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const A = styled.span`
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
`;

const B = styled.input`
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const C = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: ${props => (props.checked ? 'none' : 'solid 0.1rem #dddddd')};
  background: ${props => (props.checked ? 'black' : 'black')};
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;

  ${Icon} {
    visibility: ${props => (props.checked ? 'hidden' : 'visible')};
  }
`;
const D = styled.span`
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export default Checkbox;
```

You don't have to pay attention to the tag name.
I was so tired that I couldn't care about name.

I really want to fix this!!

Comment: I didn't see, where u call ```onChange={changeOption}``` in the child component? Inside ```<B type="checkbox" isChecked={isChecked} {...props} />```? could u please share how the ```onChange``` called?

Comment: I tried to replicate this, and it was working. Is it possible to include a sandbox link where it's not working so that others can help you better?

Comment: @Kankan-0 
How can it work?
Did you copy the code and it work? 
I'm so confused. 
I don't know how to use a sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using an input checkbox and a svg on top of that. So even though your checkbox is getting toggled, the svg is not changing based on the toggle state.

Also since `<B type="checkbox" isChecked={isChecked} {...props} />` is an input checkbox component, and you're controlling the component value, you need to use a `checked` property. I think `isChecked` is mistyped.

So if you update `isChecked` to `checked` and pass the `checked` value to the svg to dynamically update the CSS, it will work properly.

Here's a [working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-hqq6j?).

Updated CheckBox.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

function Checkbox({ isChecked, ...props }) {
  return (
    <LabelLabal>
      <A>
        <B type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} {...props} />
        <C>
          <D>
            <Icon checked={isChecked} viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12" />
            </Icon>
          </D>
        </C>
      </A>
    </LabelLabal>
  );
}

const Icon = styled.svg`
  fill: none;
  stroke: ${(props) => (props.checked ? "white" : "none")};
  stroke-width: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  stroke-width: 4;
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

// rest of the styling
```

Comment: You're such a genius. Thank you so much!